# Storing data into a DB using react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, I managed to create a form to enter data and files via the form but I don't know what are my options to save it in a centralised place. I am wondering what is the best and easiest way to store data from that form to a DB, I can build the form but I don't know what are my options to store it in a DB so I have all the data in one DB on a server as we do with web applications, so I will have an app that will work on android, iOS and web version too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relation DB if you prefer, for example, https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-sqlite-2/
However, from my point of view, it is better to use key/value storage in your case. One of the fastest implementations is https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv